# What salary range should I ask for an OPT opportunity?

Tags: salary, job-offer, internship

I am an international student in Computer Science in the Los Angeles area. As I am graduating for my Master's Degree, I am planning to start working with an OPT, Optional Practical Training (full-time).

While doing a job interview for a Full-stack (Javascript) position, I have been asked if I had an idea of how much I would like to be paid (per year in dollars). The answer is that I don't know what I can reasonably ask. If I was on a regular working visa, I would totally know, but I feel that with an OPT it's different

I have more than three years of experience in the particular domain, and worked in 3 companies before as a Fullstack too.

For people in my case that got hired through an OPT, I would love to get some feedback. For people that hired OPTs, how much would you be willing to offer for an OPT ?

I don't want to give information about the company and the job, I just want a simple range so I can have a better idea. Nothing too specific.

Comment: Keep in my that it is more precise than just a "what should I be paid question", I'm talking about a CPT with is a precise type of job opportunity for internationals

Comment: I just learned about OPT's but from what I read it seems to be only a matter of immigration regulation. Why do you think you should be paid less ?

Comment: What is an OPT ?

Answer (score 0):

You already worked in your field, so take your previous salary and add an amount that you think reflects your gained experience since then and if applicable compensate for inflation.

Unless you desperately need the job you shouldn't go below your previous salary.

Even then, avoid severely underselling yourself.

Comment: It is not that easy since I worked in an other country. This is why I am doing an OPT.
Salaries in the US are completely different

Comment: @Scaraux if you're coming from a so called western / 1st world country I found that A)it makes much more sense to set your price according to where your base(i.e. main residence) with its upkeep costs is, and to compensate for higher living costs "abroad" B)the variations in pay between those countries for non minimum wage jobs are fairly small. C)avoid going below your usual paygrade. - This doesn't mean to ignore the local wages,you might be able to get more but don't accept much less.your worth already has a number.If they won't pay that,why even bother,unless it's better scenery or job(;